# Error Importing .Reg file using re,exe from Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, registry

I am performing an export of HKEY_Current_User using the following command

```
$path = "C:\Temp"
REG EXPORT HKEY_Current_User  $path\HKEY_Current_User.reg
```

This works and exports the file

When i try to import the file using the following command

```
 reg import $path\HKEY_Current_User.reg
```

I get an exception

> "Error accessing the registry"

I am running my powershell script from the cmd.exe line and i ran the cmd.exe as administrator.

Any ideas?

Part 2

Is there a way to export the entire registry using reg.exe?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regedit by sending it commandline arguments.

> regedit /E C:\Temp\backup.reg "HKEY_CURRENT_USER"

Ref: https://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html

Comment: If i do an export. then add a key. Then do a import the added key is still present. Any ideas?